# Update row in Gridview?

Tags: c#-4.0, gridview

I have updated a row in Gridview but it is not working.

Here is my code :

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    //Label lbldeleteid = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1");
    string bname= GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["manufacturer"].ToString();
    TextBox tbmanu = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[1];
    var myString = tbmanu.ToString();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("manu_upd",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@manufacturer", SqlDbType.NVarChar,100);
    cmd.Parameters["@manufacturer"].Value = myString;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

    BindData();
```

I got the following error :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 
>       'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

here is my Grid view :

```
          <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="manufacturer" ForeColor="#333333" 
                GridLines="None" Width="400px" BorderStyle="Double" 
                CellSpacing="3" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" ShowFooter="True" 
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" 
                onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing"     
                onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
                onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
                AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"/>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number" ItemStyle- 
                         HorizontalAlign="Center">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Label ID="lbnaumber" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                                          Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>'></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manufacturer" 
                         SortExpression="manufacturer">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                                Bind("manufacturer") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbmanu" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                                Bind("manufacturer") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <%--<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />--%>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF"/><FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" 
                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"/>
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" 
                        HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" /><SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" 
                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB"/>

                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />

                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />


                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />


         </asp:GridView>
```

When I change the index of my text box 1 to 3 it shows me below error :

> **Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index**

When i change its index 3 to 2 it gives me below error :

> **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlLinkButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.**

I have one required field validator in my form but when I enable that validation update in grid view is not working.

Comment: can you show the gridview? what controls do have in it?

Comment: Well your `textbox` position is not what you have described in your `FindControl` code ,See Cell numbering starts from zero.Check updated answer.

Comment: I am really sorry about it , See Your `Cell` contains three control two `label` and one `textbox` and counting for cell number and it's control starts from zero , So i think the number of  your control will be 2 rather than 3 or 0(sorry :-)) ,this error comes when you have declared something that doesn't exist in our case we have declared `Control[3]` and total number of controls are 3 but it's 0,1,2 so your textbox is located at third position which is 2.

Comment: I hope it helped also you can not directly convert your control to string so you have to select it's `text` property . -Hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        TextBox tbmanu1 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("tbmanu"); 
        //or try 
        //TextBox tbmanu1= (TextBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("tbmanu");
        string  myString = Convert.Tostring(tbmanu1.text);
        cmd.Parameters["@manufacturer"].Value = myString;   
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your gridview in a asp:UpdatePanel and set the update mode to conditional.

Good Luck